# Difference between IMapper and IMappingEngine in Automapper

Tags: automapper-5

I am using `IMapper` which is configured as follows:

```
var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
      cfg.CreateMap<IAitoeRedCell, VigilantSingleProcessViewModel>();
      cfg.CreateMap<MailSettingsViewModel1, IEmail>();
    });

NInjectKernel.Bind<IMapper>().ToConstant(mapperConfig.CreateMapper());
```

And this is injected into as follows.

```
public MailSettingsViewModel(IEmailService emailService, IMapper mapper) {...}
```

But now for unit tests I see on the net that pple are refering to `IMappingEngine`.

I have a few questions.

1. What is the namespace of `IMappingEngine`?

   I checked out the following namespaces, but I did not find it.

   ```
   using AutoMapper;
   using AutoMapper.Configuration;
   using AutoMapper.Configuration.Conventions;
   using AutoMapper.Execution;
   using AutoMapper.Mappers;
   using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;
   using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Impl;
   ```

   Am I missing some other nuget package? I found only one - AutoMapper :(
2. More importantly I want to know differences and which to use when? Can someone please share links with some simple code samples.

Answer (score 1):

I also spent time on this. The following link helped me to use IMapper instead of IMappingEngine.

[IMappingEngine not recognized in AutoMapper 5.1.1](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/01/21/removing-the-static-api-from-automapper/)